# SwiftUI ScrollView Blurred Bottom Bar

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, swiftui-scrollview

I currently have a SwiftUI project where I am displaying an AirPods-inspired card view where the user will be able to pair their device to the app, I noticed that whenever the list of devices starts extending to the bottom of the screen, a blurred bottom bar starts to appear. I believe this is behavior from ScrollView

[Bottom Blurred Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG8Hi.jpg)

```
private var deviceListView: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(bluetoothManager.discoveredDevices, id: \.identifier) { device in
                    deviceRow(for: device)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 300)
        .padding(.bottom, UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0)
}
```

I thought by adding this line of code under my ScrollView, it would fix the issue, however the blurred bar still appears when the list extends to the bottom. Any suggestions?

`.padding(.bottom, UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0)`

Comment: Can you add the full code of your View? seems like and additional component, you can use the debug View tool to see which component is that.